# Handling 401 Unauthorised responses with visionmedia/superagent

Tags: javascript, superagent

**Background**

I'm using visionmedia/superagent to access my REST API. The API is currently available on a different domain and has CORS setup to allow cross domain requests from my client. To access the API securely I pass an Authorization header with an access token. The token has a short life and when it expires I can make a request for a new one using a refresh token. When an access token has expired the server will respond with a 401 error to let me know the request was Unauthorised.

**Problem**

I am trying to catch the 401 Unauthorised request with superagent, then handle the token refresh. The problem is superagent is not returning a standard response or error for the 401. I get a string response instead of an object.

**Error Response**

```
Error: Request has been terminated
Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
at Request.crossDomainError (client.js:616)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (client.js:724)
```

**Call**

```
ajax.get(api.baseURL + '/some_request)
    .accept('application/json')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.getAccessToken())

    .send({...})

    .then((sucess) => {
        //handle success, update data
    })

    .catch((error) => {
        //handle error, if 401 refresh the token and try again.
    });
```

**Additional Information**

The server is successfully handling the CORS side of things, the initial OPTIONS request is returning successfully with a 200.

I have tried using the non ES6 `.end((error, response) => {...}` method to handle responses with the same result.

I'm using superagent version "3.4.0"

I have tried catching the error event, get the same error string.

```
.on('response', (error, response) => {
    //manage error
})

.on('error', function(err) {
    //manage error
})
```

My server 401 response has a json response body, and returns a `Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8` header

```
{ 
  "name":"Unauthorized",
  "message":"You are requesting with an invalid credential.",
  "code":0,
  "status":401,
  "type":"yii\\web\\UnauthorizedHttpException"
}
```

**Question**

What do I need to do to get access to the error object for a 401 response? I want to be able to check the `error.status` to see if its a 401 so I can refresh the token?

Comment: The Error seems to be exception, not Response. Does the error occur always or just few times?

Comment: Is your server sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response ? Looks like plain old CORS error.